# Animating Transform Scale via Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, attributes, transform

So, I'm animating a SVG button and I want to animate transform property combined with a fadeout with opacity attributes via Javascript.

**The code would look like something like this:** (Considering it's coming with opacity 0 and scale 0)

(I know the way I'm doing it it's incorrect because it's overriding till last set attribute)

```
    function hiA(){
        pathA.setAttribute("transform", "scale(1)");
        pathA.setAttribute("transform", "scale(.5)");
        pathA.setAttribute("transform", "scale(1)");
        pathA.setAttribute("opacity", "1");
    }
```

**And the same but in reverse:** (Considering it's coming with opacity 1 and scale 1)

```
    function byeA(){
        pathA.setAttribute("transform", "scale(.5)");
        pathA.setAttribute("transform", "scale(1)");
        pathA.setAttribute("transform", "scale(0)");
        pathA.setAttribute("opacity", "0");
    }
```

I don't know if it's possible or if it's better to add a class with the animation on CSS.

Comment: Use `style.` not `setAttribute`:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp

Comment: And yes it possible to set class and to style this class in css with animation

Comment: please show your html

Comment: Please share your HTML too

Answer (score 2):

**you can set class and style in css: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp**

JS:

```
 pathA.className+="hiA"
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes example {
    0%   {transform:scale(1);}
    50%  {transform:scale(.5)}
    100% {transform:scale(1);opacity:1;}
}


.hiA{
    animation: example 1s;
}
```

See example:

```js
 function hiA(){
 var pathA=document.getElementById("pathA");
  pathA.className="hiA";
  setTimeout(function(){ pathA.className=""; }, 3000);
 }
```

```css
@keyframes example {
   0%   {transform:scale(.5);}
   50%  {transform:scale(1);}
   100% {transform:scale(0);}
}
    
    
.hiA{
    animation: example 3s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hiA()" id="pathA">animation me</button>
```

ED

Comment: This just works the first time you run the animation, and it has to run when opening and closing, two different animations. Plus I was trying with javascript because the other animations are made with segment.min.js.

Comment: I update anwer fix to work each  click not only first

Answer (score -1):

You could define keyframes in css:

```
@keyframes hia{
  0%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50%{
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}
```

... and so on, and then add the animation in css to a class or add it to the element with js:

```
.element{
  animation: hia 3s;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I quickly tested you example code on a SVG. It works.

But I would prefer defining the animations in CSS and simply adding and removing CSS classes to/from the SVG or its sub elements. This is a cleaner separation of concerns, in my opinion. And you enable possible performance accelerations by the browser, since it known about the animations beforehand and can do it on the GPU, theoretically.

Comment: It works but it overrides and only applyes the last transformation you put in, for example in
       `pathA.setAttribute("transform", "scale(1)");`
        `pathA.setAttribute("transform", "scale(.5)");`
        `pathA.setAttribute("transform", "scale(1)");`
It just works the last one